# issue in giving border color to div in a jsp method

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have writter function in which i have written a div code in string and then passed it to `out.println()` method. Everything works fine if I don't give `border size and color`, but when I give border color then whole div tag collapse. Here is the code:

```
String div1="<div style= border:1px solid #000000;float:left;height:100%;width:50%;>";
String div2="<div style= border:1px solid #000000;float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;>";
String div3="<div style= border:1px solid #000000;float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;>";
String field1="<p>"+test_name+"</p>";
String field2="<p>"+number+"</p>";
String field3="<p>"+max_marks+"</p>";
out.println(div1);
out.println(field1+"</div>");
out.println(div2);
out.println(field2+"</div>");
out.println(div3);
out.println(field3+"</div></div><br><br>");
```

what is the reason and way to remove this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the single colons

**Should be :**

```
style= 'border:1px solid #000000;float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;'
```

**Not**

```
style= border:1px solid #000000;float:left;height:100%;width:24.5%;
```

On a sidenote, its not a good practice to write your html styling in java code.